# PHP "Document Expired" after using the back button

Tags: php, post, smarty

I have a form where I am filing some informations in a wizard. This page is reaching by POST and displayed with Smarty. Once I filed all the informations in, I am using another post to get to another page. Now, the problem is that when I am trying to go back with the BACK button, I am geting the "Document expired" message.

Is than a normal thing while I am using POST or?

I am trying right now to use GET but nothing changes, or my GET is written wrong.

Here is a small schema:

```
Page 1 -> POST -> Page 2 (wizard) -> POST -> Page 3
```

When I try to come back from page 3 to page 2, I am geting the doc expired.

Thank you very much for your help regarding my problem.

Comment: This is normal for POST. POST is meant to change the state of the server, meaning the page you were viewing is likely to have expired, or the session of it has expired.

Comment: Thank you 2Truth, I shuld use GET instead of POST right?

Comment: GET should be used to read the server state, never to change it. (Read data from database, get information). If you're changing something on the server, use POST, not GET. The Page Expired page is nothing to be afraid of, and not something you should strive to get rid of.

Comment: I agree. GET is your way to go, but its not safe and not meant for this  (or if it's just a few values, you can also put it in a SESSION, provided you delete them once they're on page 3 - though that is bad practice - but it works)

Comment: Thank you for your @Truth and PoeHaH. In fact, in the page 1 and page 2, nothing changes on the server, I am only reading, I can also use GET. So, If I will use GET for the page 2, once I will go to the page 3, I shuld go back to the page 2 without the doc expired message

Comment: Ok, I am using GET now and no more Doc Expired page. The problem is that I am loosing all the informations I filled in the page 2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get

In my opinion, you should do this for *every* POST, at least in production.

Small example:

```
if ('GET' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) {
   //display view
}
else if ('POST' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) {
   //process input
   //update session
   header('Location: /next/page/to/view', true, 303);
}
```

EDIT: Want to point out that this old post was referring to browser submissions. In a RESTful web service you would likely respond with a 201 for POST.

Comment: Thank you @Explosion Pills, this pattern seems to be exactly what I need. Do you have an example of how to use it please.

Comment: not as such .. there are tons of different ways to do it and it depends on your situation.  The point is that if you know the user has used `POST` (check `REQUEST_METHOD`, check a `_POST` value is set -- and many more) do all your processing and then redirect.  Otherwise, emit the view.

Comment: Thank you once again. So, I have to use a session. But as I see, the session has a super global variable named $_SESSION. I shuld also save all the info in this array?

Comment: @Ana exactly; that's what the session is for.  You may also have some wrapper for handling the session too, or you can just use `_SESSION`.

Answer (score 1):

Everything is correct. When you push `BACK` on your `Page 3` you are actually trying to go to previous page - this page is generated as a reply to bowser's POST request. To view this page new POST request should be sent and page would be generated relying on POST data.

Comment: Thank you webbandit. Ok, I understand. I shuld also use GET instead of POST for the page 2 ?

Comment: Using `GET` request would solve this problem. All `posting` data in `GET` request is sent through URL, so going `BACK` for browser would mean only `go to <URL> again`.