# Passing session variables to more than 3 page and back in php

Tags: php, html, forms, session

The first page (inputform1test.php)

```
    <?php require_once('Connections/Project.php'); ?>
<?php

if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
  session_start();
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Input (Test)</title>
</head>

<body>
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="inputdisplaytest.php">
  <p>Name 
  <input type="text" name="name" id="textfield" />
  </p>
  <p>Text 
    <input type="text" name="text" id="textfield2" />
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Submit" />
  </p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Second page(inputdisplaytest.php)
To test if it's working in 2nd page(inputdisplaytest.php)

```
<?php include('Connections/Project.php'); ?>
<?php

if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
  session_start();
}

$_SESSION['name']= $_POST['name'];
$_SESSION['text']= $_POST['text'];

?>



<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Display Input (Test)</title>
</head>


<body>
<table width="200" border="0">
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $_SESSION['name']?></td>
    <td><?php echo $_SESSION['text']?></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<a href="inputdisplaytest_2.php">inputdisplaytest_2.php</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Third page(inputdisplaytest2.php)
This is the part where I got the error

```
<?php include('Connections/Project.php'); ?>
<?php

if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
  session_start();
}

?>



<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Display Input (Test)</title>
</head>


<body>
<table width="200" border="0">
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $_SESSION['name']?></td>
    <td><?php echo $_SESSION['text']?></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<p><a href="inputdisplaytest.php">inputdisplaytest.php</a></p>
</body>
</html>
```

I clicked to see if it's still working on 2nd page. (Which is not working)
I got the undefinex index problem when I go to the hyperlink and "Document Expired" when I clicked back button via browser.

How do I get the session variables back/not expire?
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the

```
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
  session_start();
}
```

just use session_start() at the beggining of your script. Even before those includes.

You can't print anything before the session_start. Check your logs for errors.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the reason you're finding this error is because you are POSTing the form data. When you POST the form data, it is sent when you hit Submit. Going back to the form will give you the message to reload the form data. If you change it to GET, your form data should stick.

Comment: Try this `session_cache_limiter('private_no_expire');`

Comment: I also recommend following this format for any forms to avoid these errors in the future: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11427371/3299609)

Comment: It's not working either (session_cache_limiter('private_no_expire');). I put it at the top after the session start() at every page (Except the form page).

Comment: @Escii you want to call it before session_start();

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove **if** statements that you're using to check if session is set, because in your case the **session_start()** is never being executed, since the **$_SESSION** array is always set by **PHP** unless you perform **unset($_SESSION)** which is deprecated, this will  unset the whole **$_SESSION** with **unset($_SESSION)** as this will disable the registering of session variables through the **$_SESSION** superglobal array. So:

   ```
   if(!isset($_SESSION)){
       session_start();
   }
   ```

   becomes:

   ```
   session_start();
   ```

   this resolves the problem of undefined index error.
2. To resolve the browser **back button** error when navigating back to the page processing your form, you have to put:

   ```
   session_cache_limiter('private_no_expire');
   ```

   before **session_start()** on **second.php** file, this line of code avoid **"Page Has Expired"** warnings, you can find more explanation here [avoid "Page Has Expired" warnings](http://shiflett.org/articles/how-to-avoid-page-has-expired-warnings).
3. Finally, after **session_start()** on **second.php** file, add the following code:

   ```
   if(isset($_POST['button'])){
       $_SESSION['name']= $_POST['name'];
       $_SESSION['text']= $_POST['text'];
   }
   ```

   to check if the form was submitted or not, if yes, you can process the data and display the page, else you just display the page using the perviously stored data on your session.

Comment: Please don't just post walls of code, explain what was changed.

Comment: I'm sorry @Andrew, it was my first answer on _stackoverflow_.I will try to detail my answers in the future, and thank you for the comment

Answer (score 0):

I have had issues with this myself, where the session variables are not passed on, and recently came across the answer.  I am sorry that I cannot credit the person who answered this in a previous post because I cannot find the post again.  Simply put, sometimes, especially on shared hosting, the sessions are not stored in the right place.  You can fix this by forcing the sessions to be saved in a particular spot.  My solution was:

```
ini_set('session.save_path',realpath(dirname($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']) . '/session'));
```

My session file is in the domain's root folder.

I then start the session:

```
session_start();
```

And then I make sure that the person is signed in:

```
if(isset($_SESSION["your_variable"])) {
$your_variable = $_SESSION["your_variable"];
//add any other session variables in the same manner
//be sure to rename "your_variable" with the name of your variable
}else{
header('Location: signin.php');
exit;
}
```

The header redirect at the bottom is where the person is going if they are not signed in or the session variable is not found, so that the session variables are passed to this page.  Note the exit, it keeps your code safer. So altogether my first lines of code are:

```
ini_set('session.save_path',realpath(dirname($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']) .   `'/session'));`
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION["your_variable"])) {
$your_variable = $_SESSION["your_variable"];
}else{
header('Location: signin.php');// or wherever your sign in happens to be
exit;
}
```

I hope this helps.